# How to assign a group of data to a pointer in a structure

Tags: c

As the below code, I would like to assign the Array to the payload in the structure

And I use memcpy to copy the data Array to payload

I supposed that I can get the data from Array, but actually it gets a zero

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t commandId;
    uint8_t* payload;
}TestStruc;

int main()
{
    uint8_t Array[4] = {0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13};
    TestStruc message = {0};
    TestStruc* mes = {0};
    memcpy(&message.payload, Array, sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0]));
    mes = &message.payload;
    printf("%d\n",mes->payload);

    return 0;
}
```

But after debugging by myself, I modified to this way as below

Because the type of uint8_t is defined as unsigned char, I think the below code looks more reasanable

But it still does not show the correct answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t deviceAddr;
    uint8_t regAddr[2];
    uint8_t lenth;
}__attribute__((packed)) MessageHandler;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t commandId;
    uint8_t* payload;
}TestStruc;

int main()
{
    uint8_t Array = "0x10-0x11-0x12-0x13";
    TestStruc message = {0};
    TestStruc* mes = {0};
    memcpy(&message.payload, Array, sizeof(Array));
    mes = &message.payload;
    printf("%c\n",mes->payload);
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Expect to show

```
0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13
```

in payload of the TestStruc

Comment: Hint: where does `message.payload` point to?

Comment: Hi @dbush
I think I understand what you mean
It should be like this 'message.payload = &Array;'

Comment: Hi  @SupportUkraine
I expect it will be "0x10-0x11-0x12-0x13"
Because the type is unsigned char

Comment: You'll need to study pointers before attempting to write this program. See the linked duplicate regarding common misconceptions.

Comment: @0983, `message.payload = &Array;` is not type-correct, but your compiler might accept it, and if so, then it would probably work (though your expected output is unreasonable).  Most correct would be `message.payload = Array;` or, equivalently, `message.payload = &Array[0];`.  Note, however, that `Array` is a *local* variable.  That's not an issue for the particular code you show, but it would be under circumstances where you wanted the message object to outlive termination of the function in which you set it up.

Comment: Sidenote: There is already a `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` defined in `stdint.h`. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `memcpy(&message.payload, Array, sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0]));` The size parameter is only correct by accident, because `Array[0]` is basically a `unsigned char` which is defined to be of size 1. As `memcpy` takes the size in bytes, you mustn't divide by `sizeof Array[0]` for any other type.

Comment: @0983 Take a look here https://ideone.com/Vth0LV There's not much explanation but maybe you can figure it out